# How to access rails console with capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I'd like to access the rails console of my remote server.
Rails version : 5.1.4
Ruby version : 2.4.3

I've tried to install the gem https://github.com/ydkn/capistrano-rails-console
and I have followed the instructions but when I do "cap production rails:console" I get an error :

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'console' (see --tasks)

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the Capfile : https://pastebin.com/uNdBuTan
/ Here is the deploy.rb file : https://pastebin.com/W8ic92Nf

Answer (score 1):

I had face same problem got resolved by adding following line in deploy.rb

```
namespace :rails do
 desc "Open the rails console on one remote server"
 task :console, :roles => :app do
   hostname = find_servers_for_task(current_task).first
   port = exists?(:port) ? fetch(:port) : 22
   exec "ssh -l #{user} #{hostname} -p #{port} -t 'source ~/.profile && #{current_path}/script/rails c #{rails_env}'"
 end
end
```

Make sure that **ssh port** is open on hosted server.

Answer (score 0):

Check thish gems:

- console: [capistrano-rails-console](https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-rails-console)
- rake db: [capistrano-rails-collection](https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-rails-collection)

Comment: Yes I have capistrano-rails-console but it doesn't work